# How to use await in post/get requests using fetch?

Tags: node.js, typescript, post, async-await, fetch

I have the following code which works but I don't like to use

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));
```

I would like to change my code in a way that the second call really waits till the result of the first call is prepared. In the current code, if I remove the above code, I can't get the expected result from the second call.
I should also mention that each call needs around 5-8 seconds to prepare the output.

```
 const url = "myUrl";
let bodyText = JSON.stringify({ data: dataResult});

await fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'header': 'myHeader'},
  body: bodyText 
}).then(async postres=> {
  if (!postres.ok) {

    console.log("error1");
  }
  if (postres.ok) {
    console.log("success1");

  }
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));

  return await fetch(postres.headers.get("something"), {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { 'header': 'myHeader'}
  });
}).then(async getres=> {
  if (!getres.ok) {
   console.log("error2");
  }
  if (getres.ok) {
   console.log("success2");
  }
  return await getres.text();
}).then(finalres=> { console.log("finalres is: " + finalres, null); });
```

Though I have used `await`, it seems that it is not really helpful.
I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Why are you using `then` if you are also using `await`? You're code is a bit difficult to understand. Are subsequent http calls depending on the previous call?

Comment: I firstly tried without await but it wasn't working at all, even without showing any error message to me. Yes, the second call depends on a custom header of the first call.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `await` logic to make the code look synchronous.
When using `await`, the next line will not execute until the operation completes.

```
const url = "myUrl";
let bodyText = JSON.stringify({ data: dataResult });

const postres = await fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'header': 'myHeader'},
  body: bodyText 
});

if (!postres.ok) {
  console.log("error1");
  return;      // return to stop execution???
}

console.log("success1");

const getres = await fetch(postres.headers.get("something"), {
  method: "GET",
  headers: { 'header': 'myHeader'}
});

if (!getres.ok) {
  console.log("error2");
  return;      // return to stop execution???
}

console.log("success2");

const finalres = await getres.text();

console.log("finalres is: " + finalres, null);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I had exactly this logic first, but it didn't help. When I run such a code, I get "not started yet" result on the last console.log() and the reason is that, as I said, it takes around 5-8 seconds to fnish the process. At the beginning, the status is "not started", then it changes to "processing" and finally it changes to "succeeded". But using this code, I alwasy get the "not started" answer.

Comment: @user1419243 Can you share an example of your code that is responsible for 'started' / 'not started'?